# Can you increase the degree of a polynomial with integer coefficients while keeping the exact same roots?

Tags: polynomials

Say I have a fifth degree polynomial $$z^5-5z^4-188z^3+986z^2+10152z-59696$$ 
with the roots $$ 7, 9-i,9 + i,-10 + 2i,-10 - 2i.$$
Say I want a sixth degree polynomial instead with the same roots. Can that be done?

Comment: Multiply the 5th degree polynomial by $(z-7)$ or $(z-9+I)$ or ...

Comment: what about multiplying by $z$?

Comment: @Pavel R.: then $6$th root will be $0$ (but given task is  *"...with the same roots"*).

Comment: @Oleg567: $(x-7)$ is the only possible multiplicand if you want the resulting polynomial to have integer coefficients (which is probably what the OP wants, although they don't say so explicitly).

Comment: @Doesntusefacebook: Please edit your Question to confirm that you would allow your sixth degree polynomial to *repeat* a root of the given fifth degree polynomial, and clarify if you require the resulting polynomial to have integer coefficients.